# how to communicate between labview and DM software

Tags: dm-script

Hello，I need to use DM software to analyse a txt file and get numbers.Each number was send to a Labview software which controls the moving stage. Then Labview tells it's done then DM will take picture and save the files. So how can this be done？I found few samples with the DM script.Please give a direction.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If speed is no issue, you could make Labview save an empty .txt. Your dm software could check if the file exists and take a picture as soon as it does. Ofcourse better, faster/safer methods exist, but I dont know how versitile your dm software is. A virtual com-port for example, ActiveX, there are many options to make software communicate with eachother.

Answer (score 1):

There are not a lot of 'outward' or 'inward' communcition possibilities in current DigitalMicrograph and some options are only available in later GMS versions. 
I also don't know the options Labview has, so you will need to find out what works and what doesn't. Suggestions are:

> If you are using **GMS 2.3** or later, you can use the command `LaunchExternalProcess()` to start any routine from within DigitalMicrograph the same way you would do from the command prompt.

If Labview allows to trigger some functionality by being called with parameters from the command prompt, this might be the easiest option. The DM-script will continue either when the launched process is finished, or after a specified time-out.

> If you are using **GMS 3.1** or later, you can do the oposite and have an outside program call DigitalMicrograph.exe with a command line parameter to trigger the start of a DM-script.

Essentially, this is the reverse of the first suggestion. Labview would need to "call" DigitalMicrograph whenever it wants the next action performed. I do not know Labview enough to judge if this is a possibility or not.

> There are script commands for serial communication via the COM port (RS232) provided your installation has the **SerialControl.dll** in the plugin-folder.

If Labview supports this, you may be able to establish the inter-program communication using this. The serial communication script calls are not officially supported, but the commands are rather self-explanatory:

```
Number SPOpen( Number port, Number baud, Number stop, Number parity, Number data )
Number SPOpen( String prefix )
void SPClose( Number serialPortL )
Number SPSendString( Number serialPortL, String string )
Number SPSendHex( Number serialPortL, String string )
void SPFlushInput( Number serialPortL )
Number SPGetPendingBytes( Number serialPortL )
Number SPGetTime(  )
String SPReceiveString( Number serialPortL, Number maxLength, NumberVariable actual )
String SPReceiveHexString( Number serialPortL, Number maxLength, NumberVariable actual )
void SPSetRTS( Number serialPortL, Boolean on )
void SPSetDTR( Number serialPortL, Boolean on )
```

> You can also establish 'communication' with a workaround as suggested by Gelliant in his answer. A DM-script can 'monitor' a specific folder on the harddrive and trigger some action whenever a (specific) file in this folder gets created or modified.

If Labview is capable of something similiar, this "write-to-disk" and "watch-for-change" method can be used to have two programs work in synchronization with each other.

If Labview does not support this directly, you may be able to achieve a similar "hacked" synchronisation by using a 3rd party 'scripting' language for the general system. I've personally used a software called [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) in the past to synchronize otherwise incompatible software to controll hardware.

> If you know C++ programming, you may get the **"Software Development Kit (SDK)"** for DigitalMicrograph and create your own Labview-communication plugin for DigitalMicrograph.

This option is of course the most versatile, as you're only limited by what you can achieve by your own C++ code. The disadvantage is, that you might need to recompile the plugin-DLL for different versions of DigitalMicrograph.

Comment: Labview is capable of calling an outside program via a command line and attach parameters two it.